# Create MySQL Database with .SQL File

Tags: mysql

I don't know much about MySQL at all. But I am trying to reverse engineer a MySQL database using Visio. I know what steps I should take to do this, but I can't get my database to show in the 'Databases' section (as below):

[image]

How do I create the MySQL database using the .SQL file and get it to show up in this list? I have tried this code: 
mysql -u username -p password database_name < filename.sql
using my own credentials of course. But that doesn't seem to work. In what folder should the .SQL file be placed if this statement is to work?

Comment: Does it give any error when you run this command: mysql -u username -p password database_name < filename.sql ?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it jumps to the next line with an arrow. But I'm not sure that I'm typing the command in correctly. Should the database_name be what I intend to save the database as or should it already exist? And where should the .sql file be saved?

Comment: @Amy the database_name should already exist.

Comment: @Michael Okay, thanks, I see. So can I create a blank database and import the .sql file into that?

Comment: You can run this command from anywhere but make sure to refer the right path of your filename.sql. Try moving to the folder where filename.sql exists and run this command as it is. The database_name is the name of the database that is already created.

Comment: @rizzz86 Thank you. Could you tell me the syntax would be if the file is just in C drive? I've tried mysql -u root ojs < C:/ojs.sql, but it doesn't give me a response, just skips to the next line. I've checked that the ojs database has been created

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1) Create a file "filename.sql"

2) Create a database in your DB in which you want to import this file.

3) From command-prompt/terminal, move to the directory where you have created a "filename.sql".

4) Run the command: `mysql -u username -p password database_name < filename.sql`. (You can also give the proper path of your file and run this command from anywhere). It might be the case that you don't have a password set for MySQL. If so, `mysql -u username database_name < filename.sql` will also work.

In your case if you have created a database with name **ojs** and also created a file with name **ojs.sql** in **C: drive** then run the following command:

***Edit:*** Put the path inside quotes.

```
mysql -u username -p password ojs < "C:\ojs.sql"
```

There is another way of importing tables in mysql. You can do it this way as well:

1) Connect your database

2) Type command "use ojs;"

3) Type command "source C:/ojs.sql"

Comment: Thanks a lot. It says "Unknown command '\o', so I changed it to a forward slash instead. Then it doesn't give an error, but still doesn't respond. Is it supposed to confirm something when the command works?

Comment: What is used to actually execute this statement? Is it just hitting Enter? Because when I press Enter, it seems to just jump to the next line and not actually execute the statement.

Comment: After executing the command with forward slash do you see the tables in your database that you want to create ?

Comment: No, there is no response at all. Like the statement hasn't been executed. Like it just skips to the next line of that statement instead of executing it.

Comment: That's ok if there is no response. Please check your database and see whether the tables that you want to create are created in your database "ojs"

Comment: Okay, I've checked and there aren't any tables, it just says Empty set.

Comment: What is in your "ojs.sql" file. Does it contains CREATE statements ?

Comment: Maybe I should try run the command from the directory. How would I do that exactly? So that I wouldn't have to do the whole C:/ thing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11789/discussion-between-rizzz86-and-amy)

Comment: Yes, it does. All 'Create Table If Not Exists' statements

Comment: Thanks very much, the second option worked nicely. Not sure where I went wrong with the first command option. Thanks :)

Comment: you need to terminate your command with a semi-colon. mysql is waiting for you to continue your statement.

Answer (score 26):

Most MySQL SQL files that create databases create the database 'on-the-fly', so you typically needn't do anything except:

1. log-in

   `mysql -u [username] -p[password]`

(Note: make sure you do NOT include a space (' ') character between the -p and the [password].
MySQL will think that [password] is the name of the database you want to connect to.
The 'general' log-in (above) does not assume you want to connect to any particular schema.)

1. source the file (do not use quotes around filename)

   `mysql> source [database_creation_file].sql`

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do it using mysql workbench

1> create a new query tab
2> `CREATE DATABASE database_name;`
3> `USE database_name;`
4> open the filename.sql file and execute it `ctrl + shift + enter`
5> all the tables in the filename.sql are created

Answer (score 1):

To create a MySQL database using a SQL file, you can follow these steps:

1. Log in to your MySQL server using the `mysql` command-line tool and the appropriate credentials.
2. Use the `CREATE DATABASE` command to create a new database with the desired name:

```bash
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

3. Use the USE command to switch to the newly created database:

```bash
USE database_name;
```

4. Use the SOURCE command to import the SQL file into the database:

```bash
SOURCE path/to/sql/file;
```

5. The database will now be created and populated with the data from the SQL file. You can verify this by running some SQL queries against the database.

It's important to note that this process assumes that the SQL file contains valid SQL statements compatible with the version of MySQL you are using. If the SQL file contains any errors or unsupported statements, they will be displayed in the mysql command-line tool, and the import process will be interrupted.